# problem in insert new data in the Database in .NET Core API

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core

I am working on .Net core 6 API and when I want insert new data, I received this error

```
InnerException
OracleException: ORA-06550: line13 column 204:
PL/SQL:ORA-00904: "ProdOperationProdOprId": invalid identifire
```

I have two table with one to many relationship:

ProdPrtm:

```
public class ProdPptm   // PPTMS Table
    {
        #region Properties

      
        public int ProdPptmId { get; set; }  //  PPTM_PTM
        public string PartSerial { get; set; }  // PPTM_PRT_SRL
        public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }  // PPTM_INS_DTE
        public string? Rework { get; set; }  //  PPTM_RWRK
        public string? ReadData { get; set; }  // PPTM_READ_DATA    داده ورودی خام
        public string? NewPartSerial { get; set; }  // PPTM_PRT_SRL_GEN  سریال جدید تولید شده 
        public string? BatchNumber { get; set; }  // PPTM_BATCH_NUM
        public int? PartGrade { get; set; }   // PPTM_PRT_GRD  درجه کیفی 
        public string? InsertUser { get; set; }  // PPTM_INS_USER
        





        #region Relations
        public int ProdEitmId { get; set; }    // PPTM_EITM_ITM
        public ProdEitm ProdEitm { get; set; }  //  Relation PPTMS -<------ EITMS 

        public int ProductModelId { get; set; }   // PPTM_EOPT_OPT
        public ProductModel ProdModel { get; set; }  // Relation PPTMS -<----- EOPTS

        public int? ProdOprId { get; set; }    // PPTM_PEOP_EOP
        public ProdOpration? ProdOpration { get; set; }  // Relation PPTMS -<----- PEOPS

        public int ProdManufacturerId { get; set; }     // PPTM_ISPR_SPR
        public ProdManufacturer ProdManufacturer { get; set; }  // Relation PPTMS -<----- ISPRS

        public string? ProdColorId { get; set; }     // PPTM_EPCL_PCL
        public ProdColor? ProdColor { get; set; }   // Relation PPTMS -<----- EPCLS

        public int? ShopId { get; set; }     // PPTM_EWCR_WCR
        public Shop.Shop? shop  { get; set; }  // Relation PPTMS -<----- EWCRS

        #endregion

        #endregion
    }
```

ProdOperation:

```
public class ProdOperation   //PEPHS Table
    {

     public int ProdOprId { get; set; }  

     public ICollection<ProdPptm> ProdPptms { get; set; }

}
```

this is part of context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProdPptm>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("PPTMS");

                entity.HasKey(e => e.ProdPptmId)
                    .HasName("PPTM_PTM");

                entity.Property(e => e.ProdPptmId)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_PTM");

                entity.Property(e => e.ProdEitmId)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_EITM_ITM");

                 entity.Property(e => e.ProductModelId)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_EOPT_OPT");

                entity.Property(e => e.ProdManufacturerId)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_ISPR_SPR");

                entity.Property(e => e.ProdColorId)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_EPCL_PCL");

                entity.Property(e => e.ShopId)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_EWCR_WCR");

                entity.Property(e => e.PartSerial)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_PRT_SRL");

                entity.Property(e => e.InsertDate)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_INS_DTE");

                entity.Property(e => e.Rework)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_RWRK");

                entity.Property(e => e.ReadData)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_READ_DATA");

                entity.Property(e => e.NewPartSerial)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_PRT_SRL_GEN");

                entity.Property(e => e.BatchNumber)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_BATCH_NUM");

                entity.Property(e => e.PartGrade)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_PRT_GRD");
                
                entity.Property(e => e.InsertUser)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_INS_USR");

                entity.Property(e => e.ProdOprId)
                    .HasColumnName("PPTM_PEOP_EOP");
            });
```

When I send data to insert method , 'ProdOperationProdOprId' property insert to query, But it should not be added.

insert method in repository layer:

```
    public async Task<bool> AddPolymeriPart(AddPolymeriPartDTO polymeripart)
    {

        try
        {
            ProdPptm entity = new ProdPptm()
            {
                InsertDate = DateTime.Today,
                ProductModelId = polymeripart.ModelId,
                ProdManufacturerId = polymeripart.ManufacturerId,
                ProdEitmId = polymeripart.CarNameId,
                PartSerial = polymeripart.PartSerial,
                InsertUser = polymeripart.InsertUser,
                ProdOprId = polymeripart.OprationId,
                Rework = polymeripart.Rework
                //ProdColorId = "",
                //ShopId = 2
            };
            await _context.ProdPolymeriPart.AddAsync(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception  a)
        {
            return false;
        }

       
    }
```

this is DTO model:

```
public class PolymeriPartDTO
    {
        #region Propperties

        public string? PartSerial { get; set; }
        public string? PartType { get; set; }
        public string? CarModel { get; set; }
        public string? ManufaturerName { get; set; }
        public string? Rework { get; set; }
        public string? OprDate { get; set; }
        public string? Color { get; set; }
        public string? BatchNum { get; set; }
        public string? SalonName { get; set; }
        public int OprationCode { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }


        #endregion
    }
```

When I comment relation between ProdPptm and ProdOperation, it works.

Comment: Try to add ` public int OprationId { get; set; }` in `PolymeriPartDTO` class.  And add `ProdOprId = polymeripart.OprationId,` when your create the `new ProdPptm()`.